# updating column with Index in postgres

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I am updating over ~8M rows in table. The column I am updating is `client_id` and table has composite index on `user_id` and `client_id`. Is it going to affect the indexing in some way ...?

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to rebuild the index when you're done updating

Comment: Well, one would hope it will affect the content of the index, or the index would be pretty pointless. Do you mean affect performance of the update or of subsequent queries using the index? Or what?

Comment: I think Index will slow down the update process but want to make sure that once I update this column then with the changed column value do I need to recreate Index to make sure it fast as it was before update ..?

Answer (score 1):

Doing a large update will be slower with indexes, since the indexes will have to be updated also. It might be an issue, or not. Depends on many things.

After the update the indexes will be as they should, but `REINDEX` might be in order to make their space usage better. If this 8M rows is majority of the table, `VACUUM FULL` *may* be in order to reduce disk space usage, but if the table is heavily updated all the time, it might not be worth it.

So if you want, you can remove the index, update and recreate the index, but it is impossible to say if that would be faster than doing update with the index in place.